# Programa se cuelga durante ejecución en c++

Tags: c++

tengo una función que hace una búsqueda en un archivo, si coincide el indice buscado copia el resto de caracteres hasta llegar al carácter |, la función se ejecuta entre 3 a 10 veces con el mismo índice pero luego se cuelga, alguien puede ayudarme indicando si hay algún desbordamiento y en que parte ya que estoy aprendiendo este lenguaje, espero puedan entenderle el código, una llamada sería asi

```
fBusqueda("Doctexto.dat", **Indice[0][0]="111111",1,6,4)
```

mi codigo:

```
void fBusqueda(char* pcDocumento, char** ppcIndices, int iCantidad, int iTamano, int iTipo)
{
    char *pcDigito = NULL, *pcResultado;
    int *iCuentas;
    bool *bFlags;

    pcDigito = new char;
    iCuentas = new int [4];
    bFlags = new bool [4];
    for(iCuentas[0] = 0; iCuentas[0] < 3; iCuentas[0]++) bFlags[iCuentas[0]] = 0;

    switch (iTipo)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            pcResultado = new char [100];
            break;
        };

        case 2:
        {
            pcResultado = new char [100];
            break;
        };
        case 3:
        {
            pcResultado = new char [500];
            break;
        };
        case 4:
        {
            if (bActivado == 1) pcResultado = new char [50000]; else pcResultado = new char [100000];
            break;
        };  
    };

    ifstream rEntrada (pcDocumento, ios::in|ios::binary);
    if (!rEntrada.good())
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Falló apertura de documento.", "Error!", MB_ICONERROR|MB_OK);
        PostQuitMessage (0);
        return;
    };

    for(iCuentas[0] = 0; iCuentas[0] < iCantidad; iCuentas[0]++)    //Bucle para ejecutar proceso de busqueda por iCantidad veces.
    {
        rEntrada.seekg(0, ios::beg);
        bFlags[0] = 0;
        bFlags[1] = 0;
        bFlags[2] = 0;
        bFlags[3] = 0;
        iCuentas[1] = 0;

        do
        {
            if(bFlags[3] == 1) break;
            rEntrada.read(reinterpret_cast<char*> (pcDigito), 1);   //Lectura de cada dígito del documento.

            if (iCuentas[1] == iTamano) {bFlags[0] = 0; bFlags[1] = 1; bFlags[2] = 1; iCuentas[1] = 0;};    //Condicional si iguala el tamaño de índice con dígitos encontrados.
            if (*pcDigito == 124)   //Condicional si coincide dígito con barra de división.
            {
                bFlags[0] = 1; iCuentas[1] = 0; if(iTipo != 4) iCuentas[2] = 0; bFlags[1] = 0;

                if (bFlags[2] == 1)
                {
                    switch (iTipo)
                    {
                        case 1:
                        {
                            SendMessage(hwndCombo,(UINT)CB_ADDSTRING,(WPARAM)0,(LPARAM) pcResultado);
                            bFlags[2] = 0;
                            break;
                        };
                        case 2:
                        {

                            SendMessage(hwndList, (UINT)LB_ADDSTRING, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)pcResultado);
                            bFlags[2] = 0;
                            break;
                        };

                        case 3:
                        {
                            strcpy(ppcIndices[1], pcResultado); //Traslada a una variable externa.
                            bFlags[2] = 0;
                            break;
                        };
                        case 4:
                        {
                            bFlags[2] = 0;
                            bFlags[3] = 1;
                            if(iCuentas[0] == (iCantidad - 1))
                            {
                                SendMessage(hwndText, (UINT)WM_SETTEXT, '\0', (LPARAM)pcResultado);
                            };
                            break;
                        };
                    };                              
                };
                continue;
            };

            if (bFlags[1] == 1) {pcResultado[iCuentas[2]++] = *pcDigito; pcResultado[iCuentas[2]] = '\0';};
            if (bFlags[0] == 1) {if (*pcDigito == ppcIndices[iCuentas[0]][iCuentas[1]]) iCuentas[1]++; else {bFlags[0] = 0;};}; //Traslada dígito obtenido a cadena de resultado.
        } while(!rEntrada.eof());
    };

    rEntrada.close();
    delete [] bFlags;
    delete [] iCuentas;
    delete [] pcResultado;
    delete pcDigito;
    return;
}
```

He identificado que el problema se genera cuando la función va con iTipo = 4; antes de que se cuelgue entra a la función y entra al bucle for, pero no sale...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La función es innecesariamente compleja:

- No hace falta declarar un puntero para un único `char` ni para un array de 4 booleanos.

  ```
  char pcDigito;
  bool bFlags[4] = {false}; // Todos los valores a false
  ```
- Para cadenas de texto es preferible usar `std::string`. Así te puedes despreocupar del tamaño que tiene la cadena a almacenar.

  ```
  std::string pcResultado;
  SendMessage(hwndCombo,(UINT)CB_ADDSTRING,(WPARAM)0,(LPARAM) pcResultado.c_str());
  //                                                                      ~~~~~~~
  ```
- `icuentas` son contadores... pueden reemplazarse por variables locales
- Los *streams* de C++ tienen sobrecargados los operadores de inserción y extracción... mucho más legibles que el método `read`.

  ```
  // rEntrada.read(reinterpret_cast<char*> (pcDigito), 1);
  rEntrada >> pcDigito; // Siendo digito de tipo char, no un puntero
  ```
- Para booleanos tenemos `true` y `false` en vez de `1` y `0`. Más legible.

  ```
  bFlags[0] = false; // equivalente a bFlags[0] = 0 y más legible
  ```
- Los booleanos se pueden comparar sin usar operadores `if(flag)` es equivalente a `if(flag == true)` y a `if(flag == 1)`

  ```
  if(bFlags[3]) break; // equivalente a if(bFlags[3] == 1) break;
  ```

Aplicando todo esto el programa gana unos cuantos puntos de calidad, sencillez y legibilidad. Los fucientes para encontrar al menos un punto peligroso:

```
bFlags[0] = 1; iCuentas[1] = 0; if(iTipo != 4) iCuentas[2] = 0; bFlags[1] = 0;
```

¿No ves nada raro en esta línea? Ah claro, es porque alguien la ha programado sin cariño y sin tabular correctamente el código:

```
bFlags[0] = 1;
iCuentas[1] = 0;

if(iTipo != 4)
  iCuentas[2] = 0;
  bFlags[1] = 0;
```

¿Mejor así? ¿No ves nada raro en el `if`? Ese `if` solo afecta a `iCuentas[2] = 0;`. La siguiente instrucción se ejecutará **siempre** y no es que tu código sea precisamente facil de entender, pero apostaría a que tu pretendías que el bucle afectase a ambas instrucciones:

```
if(iTipo != 4)
{
  iCuentas[2] = 0;
  bFlags[1] = 0;
}
```

Si ese no es el problema lo siento, tu código es demasiado enrevesado para entender el significado de cada flag y elemento de `iCuenta`. Quizas si las variables tuviesen nombres adecuados a su utilidad...

Ah si, y salvo en el caso de que estés declarando clases o estructuras, las llaves **no terminan con punto y coma**

```
case 4:
{
    if (bActivado == 1) pcResultado = new char [50000]; else pcResultado = new char [100000];
    break;
};
 ^ <<--- NO

if (!rEntrada.good())
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Falló apertura de documento.", "Error!", MB_ICONERROR|MB_OK);
    PostQuitMessage (0);
    return;
};
 ^ <<--- NO
```

Comment: Ah, y el código dentro de un *case* no necesita ir entre llaves

Comment: @SJuan76 eso es opcional. `switch` no crea un ámbito propio, por eso muchos programadores suelen crear uno explícito con las llaves. Es algo necesario si necesitas declarar una variable dentro de un `case`

Comment: Se resolvió el problema del desbordamiento del programa con el uso de string, mas sencillo de usar, parece que el problema pasaba por el puntero pcResultado de 100000, se hizo mas lento pero no se cuelga, cuando uso el operador >> no lee espacios del fichero binario, así que mantendría el read, y sobre el punto peligroso estaba bien solo que lo incluí en medio que le hace ver raro, jajaja, me ayudaron mucho, gracias.

Comment: @Fer para leer esapcios usa `getline`

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que las cadenas de caracteres (char*) almacenan al final del arreglo en la ultima posicion el caracter '\0' para indicar el fin de la cadena y este ocupa otro byte, intenta darle un byte de mas a cada char*